# Updating Teneo to version 1.2

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, version, teneo

I have Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.1
with Teneo 1.1.2

I'm studying the tutorial [EMF-Development](http://www.rcp-vision.com/?p=1157&lang=en)

And there are instruction how to update my Teneo to version 1.2.0 [here](http://www.rcp-vision.com/?p=542&lang=en)

I do all what is written there, but Eclipse gives a mistake:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: EMF Teneo Hibernate Runtime 1.2.0.v201211052304 (org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.feature.group 1.2.0.v201211052304)
>     Missing requirement: EMF Teneo Hibernate 1.2.0.v201211052304 (org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate 1.2.0.v201211052304) requires 'package org.hibernate.criterion [3.6.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMF Teneo Hibernate Runtime 1.2.0.v201211052304 (org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.feature.group 1.2.0.v201211052304)
>       To: org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate [1.2.0.v201211052304]

I have tried everything. And now I don't know what to do.